# Call yml file into main yml file based on condition AZ Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have main yml file for my pipeline. Is it possible to call/use another yml after condition is met in a task of main yaml?

```
- task: VSTest@2
  conditions: eq(${{ parameters.Update }}, 'true')
  ## use pipeline2.yaml to continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops

Copied from the link:

```yaml
# File: simple-param.yml
parameters:
- name: yesNo # name of the parameter; required
  type: boolean # data type of the parameter; required
  default: false

steps:
 - script: echo ${{ parameters.yesNo }}
```

and

```yaml
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- main

extends:
  template: simple-param.yml
  parameters:
      yesNo: false # set to a non-boolean value to have the build fail
```

Also note you don't have to extend a template, you can just insert a template:

```yaml
# File: templates/include-npm-steps.yml

steps:
- script: npm install
- script: yarn install
- script: npm run compile
```

and

```yaml
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - template: templates/include-npm-steps.yml  # Template reference
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - template: templates/include-npm-steps.yml  # Template reference
```